# What are the EASA external aircraft lighting requirements for day/night/VFR/IFR operations?

Tags: general-aviation, easa-regulations, aircraft-operations, aircraft-external-lights

I have attempted to decipher the EASA rules related to non-commercial small aircraft external lighting requirements (for a pilot) for the various types of flight, and I can only find the MEL for complex aircraft.  Can someone point me to the requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For EASA (via [europa.eu](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32012R0923&qid=1616760714978&from=EN), [Easy access version](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/easy-access-rules/online-publications/easy-access-rules-standardised-european?kw=lights%20to%20be%20displayed)), which is very similar to ICAO Rules of the Air (Annex 2):

> #### SERA.3215   Lights to be displayed by aircraft
>
> (a) Except as provided by (e), at night all aircraft in flight shall
> display:
>
> 1. anti-collision lights intended to attract attention to the
>    aircraft; and
> 2. navigation lights intended to indicate the relative path of the
>    aircraft to an observer and other lights shall not be displayed if
>    they are likely to be mistaken for these lights; or
> 3. in the case of balloons, position lights.
>
> (b) Except as provided by (e), at night:
>
> 1. all aircraft moving on the movement area of an aerodrome shall
>    display navigation lights intended to indicate the relative path of
>    the aircraft to an observer and other lights shall not be displayed if
>    they are likely to be mistaken for these lights;
> 2. unless stationary and otherwise adequately illuminated, all
>    aircraft on the movement area of an aerodrome shall display lights
>    intended to indicate the extremities of their structure, as far as
>    practicable;
> 3. all aircraft taxiing or being towed on the movement area of an
>    aerodrome shall display lights intended to attract attention to the
>    aircraft; and
> 4. all aircraft on the movement area of an aerodrome whose engines
>    are running shall display lights which indicate that fact.
>
> (c) Except as provided by (e), all aircraft in flight and fitted with
> anti-collision lights to meet the requirement of (a)(1) shall display
> such lights also during day.
>
> (d) Except as provided by (e), all aircraft:
>
> 1. taxiing or being towed on the movement area of an aerodrome and
>    fitted with anti-collision lights, to meet the requirement of (b)(3);
>    or
> 2. on the movement area of an aerodrome and fitted with lights to
>    meet the requirement of (b)(4);   shall display such lights also
>    during day.
>
> (e) A pilot shall be permitted to switch off or reduce the intensity
> of any flashing lights fitted to meet the requirements of (a), (b),
> (c) and (d) if they do or are likely to:
>
> 1. adversely affect the satisfactory performance of duties; or
> 2. subject an outside observer to harmful dazzle.

You might want to refer to a country's specific AIP just to be sure that there aren't local differences.

Not to be used in lieu of the above, AIP, or airport textual data, what follows is my summary by light type:

- navigation lights:

  - in-flight at night
  - moving on movement area at night
  - stationary and inadequate area illumination
- anti-collision:

  - in-flight by day and night
  - taxiing; being towed -- unless too dazzling; generally in busy controlled airports the ATC will ask for them to be switched off; see (e)
- red beacon (or similar):

  - engine running day or night on movement area

Comment: Is there any difference between VFR/IFR?

Comment: @Bianfable: nope, it would have said. Also thanks for the edit, this is better.