# What is the difference between position and navigation lights on light training aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, navigation, terminology, aircraft-lighting

What is the difference between position and navigation lights on light training aircraft (or general)? When I search for both, I find the same lights: red on the left, green on the right, and white on the back... Are they the same thing or is there a difference?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Position** lights,  sometimes called **Navigation** lights, are the same thing.

In the U.S., [14 CFR Part 91.205 (c)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91#p-91.205(c)(2)) refers to these lights as "**position**" lights.

Comment: EASA calls them "navigation lights", see e.g. [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/85159/33692)

Comment: Interesting choice by the FAA as, like many things in aviation, the rules have typically come out of the maritime world. In the US, [Title 46](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-46) refers to the equivalent lights on vessels as "navigation" lights. Which actually makes more sense as in addition to position, they also convey direction of travel.